# Vector CANoe tool kit for Matlab/Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Did any one use "Vector CANoe" tool kit in Simulink. I need to do my next project with such a combination. I searched in both matlab and vector websites for the add on tool kit but couldn't find. Would any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's something that is provided by Vector, see https://www.vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/manuals/CANoe_Matlab_EN.pdf and http://vector.com/vi_canoe_en.html

Comment: I install the package from CANoe. Now i see the blocks in the Simulink. The next step is 'How to run the simulink program in CANoe'. Do you have any examples?

Comment: No, sorry. You probably better get in touch with Vector tech support or ask on a Vector forum. This isn't really a Simulink question.